# Structuring Data for Logistic Regression - Probability of Attrition Model

Tags: regression, logistic, data-transformation, dataset

I am struggling with the best method for setting up my data for building a probability of attrition model and was hoping I could get some help/ideas here.  Basically, I have a very large dataset containing 3 years worth of monthly data about customers and an indicator of when they left (if they did). I am struggling in two key areas:

1. If a customer is going to leave then we would want to be proactive and try to convince them to stay, to do this we would want to look at activity prior to the attrition event, say 3 months for example. In this case would I code my response variable as a 1 at 3 months prior to attrition and remove any rows after?
2. What would be the best way to treat the data before the event where a customer leaves?  Say a customer left in December so we make our event September, would we leave in the earlier data with a 0 as the response value vs a 1?

One example of both areas above:

```
Customer | MonthYear | Predictor_Variables | Customer_Left | Response | Keep
A        | Jan2014   | ................... | 0             | 0        | Yes
A        | Feb2014   | ................... | 0             | 0        | Yes
A        | Mar2014   | ................... | 0             | 0        | Yes
A        | Apr2014   | ................... | 0             | 0        | Yes
A        | May2014   | ................... | 0             | 0        | Yes
A        | Jun2014   | ................... | 0             | 0        | Yes
A        | Jul2014   | ................... | 0             | 0        | Yes
A        | Aug2014   | ................... | 0             | 0        | Yes
A        | Sep2014   | ................... | 0             | 1        | Yes
A        | Oct2014   | ................... | 0             | 1        | No
A        | Nov2014   | ................... | 0             | 1        | No
A        | Dec2014   | ................... | 1             | 1        | No
```

In this example, would I keep the rows up until the response=1 and delete the rows after as indicated in the Keep column? Is there a more effective way to set up the data? I know this seems rather basic but it has been a while since I have built a model such as this and can't remember the best practices.

Comment: maybe I misunderstand, but I think your best bet is to look at discrete time survival/multistate models (which are still just using logistic regression). so the event would be december and you enter eg time on platform as one of your predictor variables, and keep all times up to dec 2014

Comment: You know, I was actually thinking of doing just that as well, in my past I did a lot more logistic modeling than survival modeling so I will have to do some more research first. Thanks for the response.